# When changing a site domain name with Google Webmaster Tools, how can I verify both sites?

Tags: domains, google-search-console

When changing a site domain name with Google Webmaster Tools, how can I verify both sites?

Google seems to require that both sites are simultaneously validated (by the same method) but with different meta tag codes. This is obviously impossible to achieve.  I can't seem to to use the "change of name" function as even if I put *both* meta tags in the header at the same time (which allows me to validate both sites) the transfer fails as Google then seems to re-check the meta tags and finds the wrong one for one of the sites.

Am I doing something wrong?

All that's happened is that the domain name has changed, so it's not possible for me to use different meta tags on different sites.  Is there a way I can tell Google about the domain name change?

Comment: Can't you just verify by another means like uploading the file to the server?

Comment: I can't - Google requires that both sites are validated by the same method :(

Comment: Select a different validation method for both then. Neither have to use a meta tag for verification.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Let me try that...

Comment: Hmm, now it wants me to verify the root URL (without the www.) which I have no (easy) control over so I think I'll have to give up. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: No, that's easy enough to do as well. Just add the non www version of the domain in Google Webmaster Tools and hit verify with the same method - it will verify this one as well then.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to verify for domains where you don't have a live site is via DNS. Go into **Alternate Methods** and Google Webmaster Tools will provide you with a TXT record that you just need to add to your domain, regardless of whether you have any content on it.

See this from Google Webmaster Tools for more info: [Verification: Domain name provider](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/176792)

Answer (score 1):

If the above does not work then you have to use the header validation. You can put that along with an HTML redirect on a page and try that.